# Proof of the continuous limit for a rotor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I have a rotor with hamiltonian
$$ \hat{H}= \frac{ \hat{L}^2 }{2I} $$
then the spectrum can be write as
$$ \epsilon_j = \frac{j(j+1) \hbar^2 }{2I} \quad \quad j=0,1,2,3,4,... $$
with degeneration level
$$ \Omega(\epsilon_j) =2j+1 $$
The partition function is
$$ Z = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \Omega(E_j) \cdot \exp[-\beta \cdot E_j] =  \sum_{j=0}^\infty (2j+1) \cdot \exp \left[-\beta \cdot \frac{j(j+1) \hbar^2 }{2I} \right] $$
Now I want to proof that this partition function can be write as an integral for high temperature limit, but I'm not sure how can be done in a formal way and not only said

$$ Z = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (2j+1) \cdot \exp \left[-\beta \cdot \frac{j(j+1) \hbar^2 }{2I} \right] \approx \int_0^\infty dj\cdot (2j+1) \cdot \exp \left[-\beta \cdot \frac{j(j+1) \hbar^2 }{2I} \right]  $$

I don't even know if this expression is correct or should I add something more, because I'm not sure where it came from. Maybe it is cause

$$ j=0,1,2,3,4,...\to \Delta j=1$$
Then
$$  Z = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \Delta j \cdot  (2j+1) \cdot \exp \left[-\beta \cdot \frac{j(j+1) \hbar^2 }{2I} \right] \approx \int_0^\infty dj\cdot (2j+1) \cdot \exp \left[-\beta \cdot \frac{j(j+1) \hbar^2 }{2I} \right]  $$

Would be this a possible explanation? Under what conditions?

Comment: Does [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13779/how-to-make-approximation-of-rotational-partition-function-of-diatomic-linear-mo) help?

Comment: Is a really exemplary answer. I never hear about Euler-Maclaurin formula. Thank you very much